# Double border bottom mat input angular

Tags: css, angular, forms, material-design

I'm using Angular 4.4 and Material Design to develop a back-office and I saw something very weird on several forms. I took a screenshot because it's hard to explain. It's like a double border bottom but I didn't find the problem when I'm using the Chrome's inspector.

[image]

```
<mat-input-container class="form-input">
  <input matInput name="firstname" maxlength="255" placeholder="{{ 'user.form.fields.firstname' | translate }}" required [(ngModel)]="currentUser.firstname" />
</mat-input-container>

<mat-input-container class="form-input"> <input matInput type="text" name="lastname" required [(ngModel)]="currentUser.lastname" placeholder="{{ 'user.form.fields.lastname' | translate }}">
</mat-input-container>

<mat-input-container class="form-input"> <input matInput type="email" name="email" required [(ngModel)]="currentUser.email" placeholder="{{ 'user.form.fields.email' | translate }}">
</mat-input-container>
```

Any idea to avoid this css ?

Comment: Could you share the working code like fiddle or something...?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the bug on plunker but it didn't work... D you know if there is a template angular 4 & material design 2.0.0.12 on plunker or fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `height: 0` and it should restore the border properly. My guess is they forgot to include it for `input[type="email"]`

Comment: Where should I add "height:0" ?

I have a div "mat-input-underline". The height is "1px" and I think that's good because the previous input is good.